# Linux command line for find storage device product name

Tags: linux, storage

I'm trying to create a tool that captures system hardware configuration. I work in a team where we constantly share different test servers and the hardware configuration can change from person to person. I want to list all the hardware that has been installed in the server in order to document different hardware test configuration.

As a part of the tool I want to capture the product name of all storage devices on the server (NVME drives, SATA SSDs, HDDs).

Is there a command line utility to list product names of all storage devices.

I am trying this on Ubuntu 18.10.

I have tried

`sudo lshw -class disk -class storage -short` 
(Got the best results with this,but this works well only for some classes of storage hardware)

`sudo nvme -list`
 (Can't translate model name to product name. When I google model name I can't find corresponding product name)

`sudo parted -l` 
(Can't translate model name to product name. Same issue as above)

Comment: What is product name and model name? Can you give some examples? The kernel may just not know the model name or product name of the device. Ok. How did you get that product name? Why would you think that product name would be available on the device in some form of downloadable data? I think using SMART would be the best, but still not always work, on systems not supporting it and on drives not supporting it.. This information is just not shared.

Comment: Product name : Optane DC P4800X Series SSD , Model : INTEL SSDPE21K375GA

Comment: How did you get the "product name"? Where from? I think the tools just report the information from `/sys/block/*/device/model`. Not all devices support ATA and such protocols. If a device supports smart, you can use smartctl, but still it not always works.I think the `/sys/block/*/device/model` is the best you can get. I think the 'INTEL SSDPE21K375GA' identifies the device very reliably. The solution for you would be to just build a database that will map the model to your product name.

Comment: I got the product name from `sudo lshw -class storage -class -disk -short` . I thought since the product name is available for some classes of hardware it could be available for other classes as well. My thoughts around this were that there has to be a way to find out what hardware has been installed on the server without opening up the server. I'll spend some more time researching your inputs

Comment: Nice. If so, I would go to lshw sources and find out where from it finds that information. Can you post a small snippet, example output from lshw where lshw reports the product name? When you find the syscall/ioctl/fnctl/anything that will get you that information, you can find out why it doesn't works for the others. And hope it doesn't use just what I said, a [map](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lyonel/lshw/master/src/manuf.txt) or [this map](https://github.com/lyonel/lshw/blob/master/src/pnpid.txt) of models to product names.

Answer (score -1):

You can use these commands to get detailed info about system hardware configuration:

```
lshw -class disk -class storage 
lspci -tv
hwinfo --storage
```